# How to inject classes when appending rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have some trouble with class when I add rows in javascript.
It applies only common class like (text-left etc.) but customized class.
This is code

```
content = '<tr id="list">';
content += '<td><input type="text" class="text-left myClass" /></td>';
content = '</tr>;
$('table').append(content);
```

Then I also tried this

```
$('table')
.append($('<tr>')
.append($('<td>')
.append($('<input>')
.attr('type', 'text')
.addClass('text-left')
.addClass('myClass');
```

Could you give me a hint please

Comment: what you are trying to say, it was not clear

Answer (score 1):

You had a little syntax error in your code. This code will work.

Check the code snippet below

```js
$('table')
  .append(
    $('<tr>').append(
      $('<td>').append(
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text')
        .addClass('text-left')
        .addClass('myClass')
      )
    )
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that some other styles override the myClass style so put : important on the css definition of myClass this might do the trick!